# Remove first n elements from array of Int in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

How can I remove the first `n` elements from an array of `Int` in Swift?

For example:

```
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
let n = 4
```

The result array contains these elements:

```
[4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
let result = Array(array.dropFirst(n))
```

(Thanks to KPM and WolfLink for pointing out that `let result = array.dropFirst(n)` sets `result` to an `ArraySlice` which will not remain valid if the original array is released.)

Comment: Be careful, this would just return a subsequence, i.e. a special view on your array that avoids the n first elements. The memory would still be there, hanging around.

Comment: @KPM The memory must indeed be there hanging around. If it doesn't how can we access the original array?

Comment: Il _will_ still be there after you release the original array, because the subsequence would still hold onto the whole original array.

Comment: The `result` in this case is an `ArraySlice` with indices that remain the same as in the original array.  Trying to access `result[0]` will result in an Index Out Of Bounds error.

Comment: `let result = Array(array.dropFirst(n))` will make `result` a separate array with its own indices (such that `result[0]` will be valid, assuming result is not empty)

Answer (score 7):

Slightly more succinct than Mr. Johnson's answer:

```
let result = array.suffix(3)
```

I'd still go with his because `dropFirst` is more intuitive / readable than `suffix`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a range to slice the Array:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
let n = 4 
print(array[n..<array.count]) //[4,5,6]
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me anymore: `Cannot subscript a value of type '[String]' with an index of 'CountableRange<Int>'`.

Comment: Be careful, this would just return a subsequence, i.e. a special view on your array that avoids the n first elements. The memory would still be there, hanging around.